# get custom event from control in repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have this markup Main.ascx:

```
asp:Repeater ID="rptSource" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <uc1:CustomControlsUC ID="CustomControlsUC1" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Container.DataItem %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in CustomControlsUC.ascx

```
Public Event Entered(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
```

and

```
 Public Sub CustomValidation(sender As Object, args As CommandEventArgs)

    RaiseEvent Entered(Me, args)
  End Sub
```

and in my Main.ascx where is repeater i try to handle this event.

```
Protected Sub rptSource_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptSource.ItemDataBound
    Dim rpt As inc_CustomControlsUC = CType(e.Item.Controls(1), inc_CustomControlsUC)

    AddHandler rpt.Entered, AddressOf HandleThis
  End Sub
```

but in this part AddHandler rpt.Entered, AddressOf HandleThis, I not have this Entered event:

How can i do this?

Comment: The only questions I can see here are "I not have entered" and "How can I do this?" Neither make any sense to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i try to catch this event in Main.ascx page, and handle here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSource" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
   <uc1:CustomControlsUC 
      ...
      OnEntered="HandleThis"
   />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```